# Power supply noise reduction

Tags: power-supply, audio, noise, emi-filtering

I am new to electrical Engineering and would like to know wich noise reduction filter ist better for use in audio equipment.

Some decalcifications:
VBUS --> 5V from usb-port
GND --> Ground from usb-port
INT_GROUND --> Internal ground I use for all my components (I just like to separate these two grounds)
Output Voltage is 15V

The first one is not my own design. I found it on the internett without description.
The second one was made by me using the datasheet of my [NMA0515SC](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/281/1/kdc_nma-2941086.pdf)

[image]

[image]

Im also confused when to use polarized capacitors. Or does it even change something?

As @Fred Cailloux can't open the sheet i will upload a screenshot of the used page:
[image]

Comment: Which is better depends on what kind of noise you have. Do you know what must be filtered out, and by how much? Or even why? Also, you are violating USB specs by the tons. You have 4400uF capacitance on USB power pins, allowed amount is 10uF. If you need that much capacitance, throw out this garbage power converter and get an adequate one.

Comment: @justme - I am really curious why would there be an upper limit to capacitance on power pins of USB? What would go wrong if someone uses higher capacitance in general?

Comment: Is it my PDF reader ?  I cannot open this datasheet NMA0515SC. It requires a password.  Even tried the original from Murata web site, need password ???

Comment: @FredCailoux I just added a screenshot of the used page

Comment: @Justme I need the noise reduction as I am using the circuit in a audio pre-amp. Am i interpreting your answer right that the second one better as it only uses 2uF capacitance?

Comment: @Whiskeyjack Why would there be a specifications for anything and why would devives need to be made according to specifications? To make devices compatible with each other. Plug that 4400uF capacitor to your laptop and see if it shuts the port down gracefully, or blow a fuse.

Comment: @PhilippBleimund I did not give an answer or hint which one is better. As a filter you are comparing 1st order RC filter with big honking capacitor to a 2nd order LC filter basically. Use a simulator to simulate which attenuates more the frequencies you want filtered. If you say you need a filter, how do you know need one, and what specs you need from the filter?

Comment: @Justme Ok im doing that. I will look more in the Frequency i need. To the USB specification can i just replace the two 2200uF capacitors with two 5uF capacitors?

Comment: @PhilippBleimund That makes little sense. Why would you want to put two non-standard 5uF caps? Or why two caps at all?

Comment: @Justme, *that makes little sense...or why two caps at all?*. It's very commonplace. Lower composite ESR, simplifying BOM, sometimes better mechanical fit etc.

Comment: I don't like either of those filters because of the 100 ohms (200 series) resistance which is not ideal. As your converter has a relatively low switching frequency and you don't require much power, I would strongly consider using dual LDOs after the switcher. It'll cost a few dollars extra, but with the right parts you can attenuate that switching frequency by 40+ dB while having low series impedance.

Comment: @Justme, I think you phrased that comment too vaguely then. Also, no-one's suggested two 2200 uF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand any filter design you need to have expectations of what is signal, noise, SNR,  voltage, current, and Impedance in terms of amplitude and f. *Then we can ask some better questions.* But realize ceramics are better than e-caps but smaller in value due to lower density so work only at the HF range.

*You need to learn/think about why and component properties to understand. I can't tell you everything here, so let's consider better questions.  Search this site for clues on ESR, DCR for ceramics and e-caps*

**Why do you ask when Murata advertises this ?**

[image]

**Since the noise is ultrasonic, >=90 kHz in this +/-15V 1W case, why do we care about HF noise you can't hear when all we care about is SNR and THD?**

This can be understood with training on impedance ratios vs frequency and component types. We know that faster rise times means higher bandwidth so for more low pass attenuation you want a bigger T=RC or smaller f cutoff.

If you ignore series and shunt resistor ratios for the moment and the resonant effects of high Q, (but expect the output resistance to be ~ <=1% of Vo/Imax) we can compare 1st order RC filters at some f with LC filters.  We see that the dual 15V 1W regulators switch at 90kHz and expect current step pulse noise on both the input and output to exist at the frequency and decline for each f decade about this.

\$f_{-3dB}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi LC}}\$

\$f_{-3dB}=\dfrac{0.35}{RC}\$

We know that Ceramic caps have much higher bandwidth (lower ESR*C) than e-caps but e-caps have lower ESR with higher C or a constant RC=T within 1 family and lower ESR with larger size and voltage ratings.

You need to learn/think about why and component properties to understand. I can't tell you everything here, so let's consider better questions.

When the amplifier responds to higher frequency noise and has some distortion or non-linearity, then sum and difference frequencies occur and are called Inter-Modulation Distortion. (IMD) The difference frequencies you can hear between the harmonics of audio and the switcher frequency. How much, depends on your ear's sensitivity to distortion < 10% or < 1% or < 0.1% and sound quality you expect.

**How does Murata get a 1W SMPS down to 8 mVpp typ., 15 mVpp max. output noise ? (for 15V version)**

- Answer: By additional filtering for Diff Mode (DM) Noise and eliminating measurement errors with common-mode noise (CM)

When you test for differential noise, all common mode noise must be blocked out.  Murata's method adds some features not always needed but is perfect for this test.
[image]

- The coax wrapped through a large ferrite ring acts as a BALUN or CM choke (T1) to reduce CM noise.
- The series 450 ohm is optional but acts as a 10:1 attenuator. The series cap blocks DC to the 50 Ohms in DSO.
- The added ceramic and tantalum cap lower the output impedance vs f.
- When two low ESR caps with T=RC each are put in parallel C_equiv=2C and ESR_eq.=ESR/2 thus impedance is 50% lower but at the same breakpoint as we know within a family of parts T=ESR*C is fairly constant.

  - This is an improvement at the expense of more area on the board instead of height with bigger and usually more expensive parts.
- Smaller and more parallel is better to keep the parasitic inductance low and Self-Resonant Frequency (SRF) higher than the noise range. But beware there are interactions that can produce high Q resonances with the wrong combinations of parts and trace inductance in higher power supplies. (nuf said)

### Recommendation

Follow Murata's advice , not something else for no reason. 2.2mF is overkill and costs much more as a tradeoff for similar effect.

Here I ignore the ceramic which becomes effective in the 100k to > 1MHz region

[image]
(Warning you cannot afford a 2200 uF tanalum cap with 20m ESR. Tantalums are 0.5 ohm cost $164 but aluminum electrolytic are >$6 38 mohm. 25V 2.2mF )

We can't compress a book on EMI into 1 page, so I hope this raises some new questions for your searching for answers.

### But remember this.

**If you do not include ESR and DCR in your simulation**, it won't be accurate.
This causes the impedance ratio plateau in the above .

### Sanity check on cost vs T=ESR*C

[image]   [Digikey](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/kyocera-avx/TWAE228K025CBSZ0000/1879539?s=N4IgjCBcoEwAwHYCcVQGMoDMCGAbAzgKYA0IA9lANogwCsABAGogC6pADgC5QgCqAdgEtOAeUwBZQtnwBXAE6EQAXyWkYVGvDgzMrJUA)  $164.08 (1)

> - ```
>   2200 µF Hermetically Sealed Tantalum Capacitors 25 V Axial, Can 500mOhm @ 120Hz
>   ```

[image]  [TDK ALum Cap $16 (1)](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/epcos-tdk-electronics/B41692A8228Q001/6160951)
(overkill)
Ripple Current @ High Frequency 8.5 A @ 10 kHz Impedance 19 mOhms 65Vdc

### BONUS

[My Simulation with selectable filters](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%200%201165286.1862176745%0Ac%20288%20160%20288%20112%200%200.0022%200%0AO%20512%2096%20560%2096%200%0Ag%20288%20192%20288%20208%200%0A170%20112%20112%2064%20112%203%2020%201000%205%200.1%0Al%20160%20112%20256%20112%200%200.00022000000000000003%200%0Aw%20368%2096%20416%2096%200%0Aw%20352%20192%20416%20192%200%0Ar%20288%20160%20288%20176%200%200.038%0Aw%20160%2080%20160%20112%200%0Ar%20160%20112%20112%20112%200%20100%0Aw%20160%2080%20192%2080%200%0Aw%20288%20176%20288%20192%200%0Aw%20288%20192%20336%20192%200%0Aw%20352%20192%20336%20192%200%0Aw%20352%20176%20352%20192%200%0Ar%20352%20160%20352%20176%200%200.1%0Ac%20352%20160%20352%20112%200%200.00001%200%0Aw%20288%2096%20352%2096%200%0Aw%20416%20176%20416%20192%200%0Aw%20368%2096%20352%2096%200%0Ac%20416%20160%20416%20112%200%200.000001%200%0Ar%20416%20160%20416%20176%200%200.01%0Aw%20288%2096%20272%2096%200%0As%20192%2080%20208%2080%200%201%20false%0Aw%20272%2096%20256%2080%200%0Aw%20272%2096%20256%20112%200%0Aw%20256%2080%20208%2080%200%0As%20288%2096%20288%20112%200%201%20false%0As%20352%2096%20352%20112%200%201%20false%0As%20416%2096%20416%20112%200%201%20false%0Ar%20512%2096%20512%20192%200%2015000%0Aw%20464%2096%20416%2096%200%0Aw%20464%20192%20416%20192%200%0Aw%20512%20192%20464%20192%200%0Aw%20512%2096%20464%2096%200%0Ac%20464%2096%20464%20192%200%201e-7%200%0Aw%20368%20320%20480%20320%200%0Ax%20192%2052%20217%2055%200%2024%20s1%0Ax%20279%2075%20304%2078%200%2024%20s2%0Ax%20337%2074%20362%2077%200%2024%20s3%0Ax%20291%20305%20518%20308%200%2014%20compare%20in%20the%20100k%20to%201MHz%20region%0Ax%20406%2072%20431%2075%200%2024%20s4%0Ao%203%2016%200%2034%205%200.00009765625%200%20-1%20in%0Ao%201%2016%200%2034%202.5%200.00009765625%201%20-1%20out%0A) with 4 switches and lots of combinations

Comment: Thanks for all that information. I will invest some more time to learn more about the topic as i am quite new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "Noise Paranoid" filter circuit I propose:
[image]
No need for bulky 2200uf, instead 2 x 100uF is better. some 0.1uf in parallel will do really good for RF filtering. Multistage is always better when filtering DC power. You do not have to worry about the capacitor size, the circuit will only take more time to charge-up.

The main difference between polarized and non-polarized capacitors is this:  Usually, in miniature electronic, non-polarized caps are of smaller values like 0.6uF down to 5pF. Their RF impedance is lower than Electrolytic capacitors which are always polarized (due to their basic chemical construction). Filtering DC need a large capacitor like 1000uF or so. These values are only available with electrolytic type. These are not much good when it comes to RF filtering, hence we add a few small ceramic or film capacitors, they have significantly smaller impedance to RF.
Check this link for more information.
[Wikipedia - Capacitors types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_types)

Comment: R1 and R3 will prevent RF resonance between L1-C1-C2 (a better scheme for filters)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you used UK and US capacitor symbols?

Comment: As Justme pointed out, USB specification for upstream facing port bypass capacitance, VBUS to GND is  1uF min, 10uF max.

Comment: That circuit is ridiculois, and you have not disclosed where it came from. The datasheet says maximum recommended capacitive loading for the DC/DC converter is 10uF, and output current is 33mA. The 100 ohm  resistor allows to charge the huge caps at 150mA. Will it even work? Also, thank you @GodJihyo I forgot to mention the 1000uF at USB pins is also ridiculous. Why would you suggest people to make circuits that violate component datasheets and specifications of standards. It might break something.

Comment: Kudo for the 1000uF not allowed on USB line. I will correct that.  As for the converter limit current, I could not know for the datasheet I tried to download from many sources keep asking for a password. One possible behavior of the NMA0515 is it will take 1 second to charge the two capacitors totaling 2000uF. I doubt this would create any problem but then again, if I had a datasheet I could access. So lets make a deal. I propose 2 x 100uF instead.

Comment: @GoodJihyo , I was not aware that those two capacitor images where of US or UK . In reality that is how OrCAD distinguish between a non-polarized or polarized capacitor. It is inherent to the software. The picture showing a flat line over an arc represent the polarized cap, where the one with two flat lines is for the non-polarized cap

Comment: So you designed a circuit without knowing how to use the components, and without specs required from the circuit, like how much current the load consumes, how much is allowed voltage drop, and how much there is noise and how much (if any) needs to be filtered out. This filter will output only 11V if load draws 20mA for example.

Comment: I my opinion it is the responsibility of the person asking the question to supply as much information as needed. As a general rule, the quality of an answer is usually proportional to the quality of the question. As far as your 20mA argument, if the circuit draws too much current for the NMA0515 then Philipp should consider another converter. The question was about filters, not load. Anyhow, thank you for your comments, they will certainly contribute to raising my level of "carefullness" for future answers.

Comment: It seems like a linear regulator would be a lot simpler for a 1W Supply  ;)   what would it look like for a 100W supply? What are your design specs? Why did you ignore ESR?